# Redux - mapDispatchToProps not working for logout function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, logout, react-props

in my app I've a logout button but it does not log you out. I've checked the reducers and the actions and they seem okay as I've another similar app and it works there.

This is the "Nav.jsx" component where the logout action is being imported.

```
import React from 'react'
import {connect} from 'react-redux'
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom'
import {logoutUser} from '../actions/logout'

class Nav extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      showBurger: false,
      loggedOut: false
    }
    this.toggleBurger = this.toggleBurger.bind(this)
    this.logout = this.logout.bind(this)
  }
  toggleBurger() {
    this.setState({showBurger: !this.state.showBurger})
  }

  logout () {
    this.props.dispatch(logoutUser())
    this.setState({loggedOut: true})
  }

  render() {
    //
    const {auth} = this.props
    const {showBurger} = this.state
    const {loggedOut} = this.state
    console.log("is this logout?", this.logout.bind(this))

    return <nav className="navbar">
      <div className="container">
        <div className="navbar-brand">
          <span onClick={this.toggleBurger} className={`navbar-burger burger ${showBurger ? 'is-active': ''}`} data-target="navbarMenuHeroA">
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
          </span>
        </div>
        <div id="navbarMenuHeroA" className={`navbar-menu ${showBurger ? "is-active" : ''}`}>
          <div className="navbar-end">
            <Link onClick={this.toggleBurget} className="navbar-item" to='/found'>Found</Link>
            <Link onClick={this.toggleBurget} className="navbar-item" to='/lost'>Lost</Link>
            {auth.isAuthenticated
              ? <span>
                <Link onClick={this.toggleBurget} className="navbar-item" to='/foundform'>Foundform</Link>
                <Link onClick={this.toggleBurget} className="navbar-item" to='/lostform'>Lostform</Link>
                <Link to="/" onClick={() => this.logout.bind(this)} className="navbar-item">Logout</Link>
              </span>
              : [
                <Link onClick={this.toggleBurger} className="navbar-item is-large" to='/login'>Login</Link>,
                <Link onClick={this.toggleBurger} className="navbar-item" to='/register'>Register</Link>,
              ]
            }
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    logout: () => dispatch(logoutUser())
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = ({auth}) => {
  return {auth}
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Nav)
```

When I run this, the console.log give me "is this logout? ƒ () { [native code] }" and I also get this warning: "Hash history cannot PUSH the same path; a new entry will not be added to the history stack". This was a group project that I'm now working on myself and I can't tell what exactly is wrong? Please help.

Here is the logout action if it helps.

```
   import { removeUser } from '../utils/auth'
    function requestLogout () {
      return {
        type: 'LOGOUT_REQUEST',
        isFetching: true,
        isAuthenticated: true
      }
    }

    function receiveLogout () {
      return {
        type: 'LOGOUT_SUCCESS',
        isFetching: false,
        isAuthenticated: false
      }
    }

    // Logs the user out
    export function logoutUser () {
      return dispatch => {
        document.location = "/#/"
        dispatch(requestLogout())
        removeUser()
        dispatch(receiveLogout())
      }
    }
```

Here are some more files from the app.This is the auth.js in the reducers folder.

```
import { isAuthenticated, getUserTokenInfo } from '../utils/auth'

const initialState = {
  isFetching: false,
  isAuthenticated: isAuthenticated(),
  user: getUserTokenInfo(),
  errorMessage: ''
}

export default function auth (state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'LOGIN_REQUEST':
      return {
        ...state,
        isFetching: true,
        isAuthenticated: false,
        errorMessage: ''
      }
    case 'LOGIN_SUCCESS':
      return {
        ...state,
        isFetching: false,
        isAuthenticated: true,
        user: action.user
      }
    case 'LOGIN_FAILURE':
      return {
        ...state,
        isFetching: false,
        isAuthenticated: false,
        errorMessage: action.message
      }
    case 'LOGOUT_SUCCESS':
      return {
        ...state,
        isFetching: false,
        isAuthenticated: false,
        user: null
      }
    case 'REGISTER_REQUEST':
      return {
        ...state,
        isFetching: true,
        isAuthenticated: false,
        errorMessage: ''
      }
    case 'REGISTER_FAILURE':
      return {
        ...state,
        isFetching: false,
        isAuthenticated: false,
        errorMessage: action.message
      }
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

And the index.js where the reducers have been combined.

import {combineReducers} from 'redux'

```
import auth from './auth'
import lostPets from './lostPets'
import found from './foundPets'

export default combineReducers({
  auth,
  found,
  lostPets
})
```

Comment: `logoutUser` is an API call or simply function

Comment: You had mapped your dispatch to props, therefore you can't use `this.props.dispatch` in that component. Considering that, you should use `this.props.logout` instead in your `logout()` function. Try updating your code and see what happens. Additionally, seems like you have an issue with your `react-router`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call the function directly instead of using dispatch since you are already using `mapDispatchToProps`, If you don't provide `mapDispatchToProps`, `dispatch` will be made available to the component

```
import React from 'react'
import {connect} from 'react-redux'
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom'
import {logoutUser} from '../actions/logout'

class Nav extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      showBurger: false,
      loggedOut: false
    }
    this.toggleBurger = this.toggleBurger.bind(this)
    this.logout = this.logout.bind(this)
  }
  toggleBurger() {
    this.setState({showBurger: !this.state.showBurger})
  }

  logout () {
    this.props.logout() // call logout here from props
    this.setState({loggedOut: true})
  }

  render() {
    //
    const {auth} = this.props
    const {showBurger} = this.state
    const {loggedOut} = this.state
    console.log("is this logout?", this.logout.bind(this))

    return <nav className="navbar">
      <div className="container">
        <div className="navbar-brand">
          <span onClick={this.toggleBurger} className={`navbar-burger burger ${showBurger ? 'is-active': ''}`} data-target="navbarMenuHeroA">
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
          </span>
        </div>
        <div id="navbarMenuHeroA" className={`navbar-menu ${showBurger ? "is-active" : ''}`}>
          <div className="navbar-end">
            <Link onClick={this.toggleBurget} className="navbar-item" to='/found'>Found</Link>
            <Link onClick={this.toggleBurget} className="navbar-item" to='/lost'>Lost</Link>
            {auth.isAuthenticated
              ? <span>
                <Link onClick={this.toggleBurget} className="navbar-item" to='/foundform'>Foundform</Link>
                <Link onClick={this.toggleBurget} className="navbar-item" to='/lostform'>Lostform</Link>
                <Link to="/" onClick={() => this.logout.bind(this)} className="navbar-item">Logout</Link>
              </span>
              : [
                <Link onClick={this.toggleBurger} className="navbar-item is-large" to='/login'>Login</Link>,
                <Link onClick={this.toggleBurger} className="navbar-item" to='/register'>Register</Link>,
              ]
            }
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    logout: () => dispatch(logoutUser())
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = ({auth}) => {
  return {auth}
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Nav)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm confused why you're using both component state and redux state to keep track of whether the user is logged out. Regardless, you pass `dispatch` to  mapDispatchToProps, and should wrap your functions you define inside mapDispatchToProps with `dispatch()` so they get sent to the dispatcher:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  logout: () => dispatch(logoutUser())
})
```

Using this kind of pattern will allow you to concentrate all dispatch calls within `mapDispatchToProps`.

Full reducer (I initialize state as logged in because I don't have access to your auth module that actually authenticates users):

```
const initialState = {
  isAuthenticated: true,
  isFetching: false,
}

const logoutReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'LOGOUT_REQUEST':
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        isFetching: true,
      })
    case 'LOGOUT_SUCCESS':
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        isFetching: false,
        isAuthenticated: false,
      })
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

export default logoutReducer;
```

Reducer is mounted in state as auth:

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import logoutReducer from './logoutReducer';

export const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  auth: logoutReducer,
});
```

Full logout actions:

```
const requestLogout = () => ({
  type: 'LOGOUT_REQUEST',
  isFetching: true,
  isAuthenticated: true
})

const receiveLogout = () => ({
  type: 'LOGOUT_SUCCESS',
  isFetching: false,
  isAuthenticated: false
})

export const logoutUser = () => {
  return dispatch => {
    document.location = "/#/"
    dispatch(requestLogout())
    //removeUser()
    dispatch(receiveLogout())
  }
}
```

Full component:

```
import React from 'react'
import {connect} from 'react-redux'
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom'
import {logoutUser} from '../actions/logout'

class Nav extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      showBurger: true,
      loggedOut: false
    }
    this.toggleBurger = this.toggleBurger.bind(this)
    this.logout = this.logout.bind(this)
  }
  toggleBurger() {
    this.setState({showBurger: !this.state.showBurger})
  }

  logout () {
    console.log('logging out')
    this.props.logout()
    this.setState({loggedOut: true})
  }

  render() {
    //
    const {auth} = this.props
    const {loggedOut} = this.state
    console.log('is this logout?', this.logout)

    return <nav className='navbar'>
      <div className='container'>
        <div className='navbar-brand' style={{
            height: '40px',
            width: '40px',
            background: 'red',
          }}>
          <span onClick={this.toggleBurger}
            className={
              `navbar-burger burger ${this.state.showBurger ? 'is-active': ''}`
            } data-target='navbarMenuHeroA'>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
          </span>
        </div>
        <div id='navbarMenuHeroA' 
          className={
            `navbar-menu ${this.state.showBurger ? 'is-active' : ''}`
          }>
          <div className='navbar-end'>
            <Link onClick={this.toggleBurger}
              className='navbar-item'
              to='/found'>Found</Link>
            <Link onClick={this.toggleBurger}
              className='navbar-item'
              to='/lost'>Lost</Link>
            {auth.isAuthenticated
              ? <span>
                <Link onClick={this.toggleBurger}
                  className='navbar-item'
                  to='/foundform'>Foundform</Link>
                <Link onClick={this.toggleBurger}
                  className='navbar-item'
                  to='/lostform'>Lostform</Link>
                <Link onClick={this.logout}
                  className='navbar-item'
                  to='/'>Logout</Link>
              </span>
              : [
                <Link onClick={this.toggleBurger}
                  className='navbar-item is-large'
                  to='/login'>Login</Link>,
                <Link onClick={this.toggleBurger}
                  className='navbar-item'
                  to='/register'>Register</Link>,
              ]
            }
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  logout: () => dispatch(logoutUser())
})

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  auth: state.auth,
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Nav)
```

I think you need to simplify greatly before proceeding or asking questions on StackOverflow. Make a simple, one component app with one div that allows users to click to login and click to logout. Then one-by-one introduce elements. When you get stuck, pare the app down to its absolute minimum viable expression of the problem, and post that as a question here and folks will be happy to help...

Comment: Hi all, thanks for your answers but I'm still getting the same errors.

Comment: @Jattsingh is this your first encounter with React (or with React Router or Redux)? This code seems quite confused; I highly recommend trying to build a simpler use case first, then building up to this authentication component...

Comment: @Jattsingh did you take a look at my updated answer? Try using `create-react-app` or some absolutely minimal boilerplate and implement the above and you should see the changes working...

Comment: Thanks for all your answers but maybe the problem is somewhere else, I've added some more code. This was a group project but I mostly worked on the react stuff and redux is still quite new to me.

Comment: @Jattsingh did you use create-react-app and use the components I pasted above? If so, what problems did you encounter? If not, I think you should try this to isolate the problem you're encountering...

Comment: It works, thank you so much. It must've been the mapStateToProps that was wrong initially. Cheers.

Comment: @Jattsingh hooray! I'm glad this got you going! Have fun exploring Redux. The Egghead.io tutorials are very good if you haven't checked them out yet...

Comment: @Jattsingh feel free to click the checkmark next to this answer so folks can see this problem has been resolved!